# Documentation of manually passing parameters ${parameter} inside query

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

Hive documented about setting variables in `hiveconf` 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

I know there is also a way of passing parameters using `${parameter}`(not `hiveconf`), e.g.

```
select * from table_one where variable = ${parameter}
```

And then the `hive` editor would prompt you to enter the value for `parameter` when you submit the query.

I can't find where `Apache hadoop` documents this way of passing parameters. Is this way of passing parameters inherent in `hive` or `oozie`? If it is `oozie` why can it be used in the `hive` editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of [Hue](http://gethue.com/).  There is a reference to this feature in Cloudera documentation, at least for older versions.  For example, the [Hive Query Editor User Guide](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hue-3.6.0-cdh5.1.0/user-guide/beeswax.html) describes it.

> PARAMETERIZATION  Indicate that a dialog box should display to enter parameter values when a query containing the string $parametername is executed. Enabled by default.